# Variable size array of pointers C++

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, size

I want to have a variable size (can be increased) array of pointers to objects of a specific class. (Wire is the class name, i is a counter, cw is a pointer to a Wire)

```
Wire **w;
...
w[i]= cw;
```

How can I allocate memory for POINTERS? (assume that cw is pointing to an existing Wire.)

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector`?

Comment: Do you actually allocate any memory for `w[]`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I want to know HOW can I do that.

Comment: @user3237431 _'I'm sorry. I want to know HOW can I do that.'_ See John Dibling's answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

`std::vector <std::unique_ptr <Wire>>`

Comment: What should I include to access std::unique_ptr? I'v included <memory> but still having trouble. I'm working with Qt Creator 2.8.1 (Qt 5.1.1)

Comment: @user3237431: I'm not familiar with that compiler.  `unique_ptr` was introduced with C++11.  Does your compiler support that?  If not, you might have to resort to using a raw pointer instead of a `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use standard container std::vector. For example

```
std::vector<Wire *> v;
```

or of some smart pointer.

If you may not use the vector then the approach is following

```
int size = SOME_VALUE;

Wire **w = new Wire * [size];

w[0] = cw;
```

Comment: Not really! Avoid raw pointers for the 1st sample, and the second at all.